# Getting XHR Issue while loading the page in angular nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

[image]

I have used the below code in index.js

```
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
```

but still I am getting the error page is not showing the results what i wanted

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,Url:'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:3000'
};
```

In environment I have given like this..

what else is to sort out the issue?

Index.js

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const db = require('./connection');
const postModel = require('./postModel');
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


app.post('/user', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, mobile } = req.body;
  console.log(name)
  console.log(mobile)
  try {
    const newPost = await postModel.create({name, mobile});
    res.json(newPost);
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});


app.get('/user', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, mobile } = req.body;
  console.log(name)
  console.log(mobile)
  try {
    const posts = await postModel.find();
    res.json(posts);
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});


app.get('/user/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  console.log(id)
  try {
    const posts = await postModel.findById(id);
    res.json(posts);

  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});


app.put('/user/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  const { name, mobile } = req.body;
  console.log(id)
  try {
    const posts = await postModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {name,mobile});
    //res.json("Updated Successfully")
    try {
      const post = await postModel.findById(id);
      res.json(post);
      //res.json("Updated Successfully");
    }
    catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});


app.delete('/user/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const {id} = req.params;
  console.log(req.params);
  console.log(id)
  try {
    const posts = await postModel.findById(id);
    await posts.remove();
    res.json("Deleted Successfully");
  }
  catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});

//Set the base path to the angular-test dist folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/frontend')));

//Any routes will be redirected to the angular app
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/frontend/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening on PORT: 3000");
});
```

[image]

https://github.com/changan1111/UserManagement project location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code locally and worked fine, I ran it on Docker and it was also fine. So for what I've read in the comments and the logs screenshots the error is actually in the way you deploy your app. When you run `docker run p 80:3000 -it {imageName}` you are publishing the port 3000 to the port 80 of the hosting machine, this means, that your frontend can only access the `/user` from the port 80 since the 3000 only exits in Docker. [Check out the docs on published ports](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports). I hope this is clear.

The solution to your problem is to update the frontend `environment.prod.ts`:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  Url:'http://{ip.of.the.hosting.machine}:{publishedPort}'
};
```

Side note: If your using 80 as the published Port, you can omit it in the `environment.prod.ts` since http://192.168.0.1:80 == http://192.168.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Your method to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not right

You can try with this method:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

You just need to replace `http://localhost:8888` with the URL of your frontend website.

This will tell to your server that requests from this frontend website will be accepted and that requests from other origins will be rejected.

Hope it will works

Comment: localhost:8888 refers to front website which means angular which is listening on 4200.. port should be 4200 right or backend is listening on 3000.. which one should i give

Comment: app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
}); No luck after adding this as well ..

Comment: Be careful you have to put the full URL when setting the header: try to replace `localhost:4200` by `http://localhost:4200`

Comment: copy paste errror.. full address only added  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

Comment: https://github.com/changan1111/UserManagement project is there..

Comment: I see `apiUrl=environment.Url+"/user";` on apiservice.service.ts but Url in environment is `http://localhost:3000/`. Try to modify the Url in environment by deleting the trailing slash, you will have `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: followed that but cors issue not rectified..

Comment: I'm a bit out of idea but can you tell me how your run both the angular application and the server ?

Comment: https://github.com/changan1111/UserManagement/blob/main/.github/workflows/dockertest.yml through github action, build the image and pushed to docker.io using docker file.. downloading that image in the aws ec2 after docker installed.. and running that docker run p 80:3000 -it {imagename}

Comment: So you're running it on docker when developing? And you are using the same container for the frontend and backend ?

Comment: yes. all the files place in the same image and running in the same container. backend refers to mongodb atlas which is called in index.js